# Need help in getting grid view image to open a new activity

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-adapter, buttonclick

I tried writing code to create a new activity when I click on a button. The buttons are actually pictures inflated in a grid view using an adapter. But for some reason I get a fatal error exception.
Here is my code for the grid layout page:

```
package com.example.yueat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Grid extends Activity {

protected static Context context;
protected static int pos;

// protected static double buttonID;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gridlayout);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            pos = position;
            Intent descr = new Intent("com.example.yueat.DESCR");
            startActivity(descr);
        }
    });
}

protected int getPos() {
    return pos;
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

Here is my code for the page I want to open upon clicking a image in the grid layout, each page should open the same activity.I would like the activity (Descr) to display the position of the clicked image in the grid in a textView.

```
package com.example.yueat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Descr extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.descr_layout);
        String convert = Double.toString(Grid.pos);
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.descrText1);
        tv.setText(convert);
}}
```

When I compiled it the code crashes when I click the image and it does not read anything in the Descr class. Any tips/suggestions/help would be appreciated.

LOGCAT ERROR:

```
05-29 22:53:17.142: W/dalvikvm(23317): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4203cda0)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317): Process: com.example.yueat, PID: 23317
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.yueat/com.example.yueat.Descr}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1636)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1430)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3532)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3493)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3735)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3703)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at com.example.yueat.Grid$1.onItemClick(Grid.java:39)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1495)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3453)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4816)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
05-29 22:53:17.142: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 22:58:17.162: I/Process(23317): Sending signal. PID: 23317 SIG: 9
05-29 22:58:17.442: I/PersonaManager(23779): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
05-29 22:58:17.502: I/PersonaManager(23779): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
05-29 22:58:17.593: I/PersonaManager(23779): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
05-29 22:58:17.673: D/AbsListView(23779): Get MotionRecognitionManager
05-29 22:58:17.703: D/context = %s ...(23779): android.app.Application@42a3d060
05-29 22:58:17.703: D/MyAdapter(23779): getItem successful
05-29 22:58:17.703: D/MyAdapter(23779): getItem successful
05-29 22:58:17.743: D/context = %s ...(23779): android.app.Application@42a3d060
05-29 22:58:17.743: D/MyAdapter(23779): getItemId successful
05-29 22:58:17.743: D/MyAdapter(23779): layout inflater successful
05-29 22:58:17.743: D/MyAdapter(23779): view row successful
05-29 22:58:17.743: D/context = %s ...(23779): android.app.Application@42a3d060
05-29 22:58:17.743: D/MyAdapter(23779): getItemId successful
05-29 22:58:17.743: D/MyAdapter(23779): view row successful
05-29 22:58:17.743: D/context = %s ...(23779): android.app.Application@42a3d060
05-29 22:58:17.743: D/MyAdapter(23779): getItemId successful
05-29 22:58:17.743: D/MyAdapter(23779): view row successful
05-29 22:58:17.773: W/Adreno-GSL(23779): <get_panel_settings:3802>: Android framework reported version 2. So, don't force ES30
05-29 22:58:17.773: I/Adreno-EGL(23779): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.00.007.018_msm8960_KK_2.7_RB1_CL3869936_release_AU (CL3869936)
05-29 22:58:17.773: I/Adreno-EGL(23779): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
05-29 22:58:17.773: I/Adreno-EGL(23779): Build Date: 12/09/13 Mon
05-29 22:58:17.773: I/Adreno-EGL(23779): Local Branch: mybranch2092625
05-29 22:58:17.773: I/Adreno-EGL(23779): Remote Branch: quic/kk_2.7_rb1.15
05-29 22:58:17.773: I/Adreno-EGL(23779): Local Patches: NONE
05-29 22:58:17.773: I/Adreno-EGL(23779): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.00.007.018 +  NOTHING
05-29 22:58:17.793: D/OpenGLRenderer(23779): Enabling debug mode 0
05-29 22:58:17.793: D/context = %s ...(23779): android.app.Application@42a3d060
05-29 22:58:17.793: D/MyAdapter(23779): getItemId successful
05-29 22:58:17.793: D/MyAdapter(23779): view row successful
05-29 22:58:17.793: D/context = %s ...(23779): android.app.Application@42a3d060
05-29 22:58:17.793: D/MyAdapter(23779): getItemId successful
05-29 22:58:17.803: D/MyAdapter(23779): layout inflater successful
05-29 22:58:17.803: D/MyAdapter(23779): view row successful
05-29 22:58:17.803: D/context = %s ...(23779): android.app.Application@42a3d060
05-29 22:58:17.803: D/MyAdapter(23779): getItemId successful
05-29 22:58:17.803: D/MyAdapter(23779): layout inflater successful
05-29 22:58:17.803: D/MyAdapter(23779): view row successful
```

ANDROID MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.yueat"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Grid"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.yueat.GRID" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Descr"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.yueat.DESCR" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code inside your *onItemClick* :

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {

        Intent descr = new Intent(Grid.this,Descr.class);
        startActivity(descr);
    }
});
```

Comment: No, the fatal exception is still thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass the position of the grid along with the intent. Your Grid class would look like this

```
package com.example.yueat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Grid extends Activity {

protected static Context context;
protected static int pos;

// protected static double buttonID;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gridlayout);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            pos = position;
            Intent descr = new Intent(Grid.this, Descr.class);
            descr.putExtra("position", pos);
            startActivity(descr);
        }
    });
}

protected int getPos() {
    return pos;
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

And your Descr class would look like this. Here you are going to get the position value from the Intent and then display it in your TextView.

```
package com.example.yueat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Descr extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.descr_layout);
        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        int position= mIntent.getIntExtra("position", 0);
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.descrText1);
        tv.setText(position + "");
}}
```

Edit: Change your Android Manifest to the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.yueat"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Grid"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Descr"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The fata exception is still thrown. Also doesn't setting position as protected static in grid and calling it later in Descr class pass on the value?

Comment: What is the actual exception that you're getting? Post your error logs in your logcat here.

Comment: No, I meant edit Your post with the Logcat, not mine. That way it will be easier for other users to see it if they run into the same error in the future. Anyway, edit your post again by adding both the logcat and a file called AndroidManifest.xml . I'm sure the error is in there somewhere.

Comment: You probably needed to rebuild the project after making the changes. Anyway it works now. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

try this code inside your onItemClick :

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
        int position, long id) {

    Intent descr = new Intent(Grid.this,Descr.class);
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(descr);
}
```

});